# HTML Form as Array with key - value pair

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

Is it possible to create a form in pure HTML so that when it is passed, the result is the array, but the 'name' becomes the index 'key' and the value becomes the index 'value'?

For instance, say my form is to have multiple `attributes`. First `attribute` is a `color`, second is a `abbv`, and third is a `cost`.

So I'd like to get an array of the following form:

```
attributes: [
    {
        key : 'color',
        value: 'the color the user picks'
    },
    {
        key : 'abbv',
        value: 'the abbreviation the user types'
    },
    {
        key : 'cost',
        value: 'the cost the user assigns'
    }    
]
```

I want to know if this is possible in pure HTML. I know I can perform this in Javascript.

Comment: not that I know of.  you can do input name="attributes[key]" I think but that would be my best guess.  You'll want it this way though, attributes[key][]

Comment: You are talking about a javascript array.. there's no array on pure HTML. Explain more if I misunderstood.

Comment: HTML doesn't have arrays.

Comment: Okay, I guess this cannot be done without Javascript reformatting it.

Comment: If you want a data structure like that when the form is submitted, then how you get it depends (mostly) on the language you are using to parse the form data. Are you using JavaScript server side (e.g. with Node)?

Comment: I am using Laravel back-end, with Angular front-end. But thanks these posts did clear things up for me1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is an `application/json` encoding type for HTML form submissions.

This type is not currently specified for HTML, which, as of version 5, [specifies three encoding types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype):

1. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
2. `multipart/form-data`
3. `text/plain`

And of course, if it were supported, there is no guarantee that it would serialize the data in the format you've specified.